# Cloud build trigger doesn't see Cloud Source Repository from another project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want create Cloud Build trigger linked to Cloud Source Repository in another project.
But when I'm on a step where I am supposed to choose a repository, the list is empty.
I tried different some permission, but without luck.
Could someone tell whether such configuration is possible and how do it?

Answer (score 2):

The cloudbuild trigger can only see repositories that are in the same project.

We ran into the same issue with Bitbucket repos that we are mirroring into the Cloud Source Repos in our projects.

What we discovered was that we needed to mirror the repo into BOTH projects so that the cloudbuild trigger could see the repository.  I am not sure how this would work with a repo that only lives in the GCP source code repo.

Answer (score 0):

When you have project A that has a trigger to build a container and place it in a repository owned by project B, you must add an IAM permission on project B that allows creation of images from a service account on project A.  When you are using triggers, a service account on project A is created called `A_number@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com`.  On project B, you must then use IAM to give permissions for this service account to create containers.  For example, you may add the role "Cloud Build Editor".

This appears to be quite well document in the following Cloud Build docs:

- [Configuring access control](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/configure-access-control)
- [Setting service account permissions](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/set-service-account-permissions#granting_additional_access)

Comment: Yes, you are right, but this don't give permisdion on Cloud Sourse Repository.  I tried add permission on ProjectB to cloudbuild service account.  I can create trigger on PojectA with github repository.  I can build image and on ProjectA and upload it to Image Registry on ProjectB.  But I can't create trigger on ProjectA with Cloud Source Repository from ProjectB.